# How to resume the downloading where it left in asynctask android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, download

For example I am downloading a file from server, in between the connectivity is lost at that point in time my download was 30%, after some time I got a connection .Now I want to start a downloading from 30%, not from 0%.How to achieve this asynctask android.

If any alternative is there please, let me know.???

Comment: Store your value in [Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first figure out how many bytes you have actually downloaded. I suggest saving your file with an different name when it's being downloaded so you can can easily see if you have an unfinished download.
Check the status of you file first to see how much you have downloaded.

```
private long isIncomplete(){
        File from = new File(dir,fileName+"-incomplete");
        if(from.exists()){
            Log.d("status","download is incomplete, filesize:" + from.length());
            return from.length();
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Then when creating your http request you can tell the server from what point to serve you the file so that you can resume download.

```
long downloaded = isIncomplete();
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes="+(downloaded)+"-");
```

See [this class](https://github.com/2hamed/android-download-manager/blob/master/Download/src/org/test/download/DownloadService.java) that I wrote a few years back for a complete implementation.

**Update:** I suggest you do not use the Shared Preferences for this. [SSOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth) states that you get the info from only one source not more hence reading the progress from the downloaded file.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the destination file path in sharedpreferences and you can do the following code.

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();//Opening the url

    File file=new File(DESTINATION_PATH);
    if(file.exists()){    //check if file exists
         downloaded = (int) file.length();
         connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes="+(file.length())+"-");
    }
else{
    connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + downloaded + "-");
}
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
pBar.setMax(connection.getContentLength());
 in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
 fos=(downloaded==0)? new FileOutputStream(DESTINATION_PATH): new FileOutputStream(DESTINATION_PATH,true);
 bout = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, 1024);
byte[] data = new byte[1024];
int x = 0;
while ((x = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) >= 0) {
    bout.write(data, 0, x);
     downloaded += x;
     pBar.setProgress(downloaded);
}
```